# Why am I getting an exception when using a Range Join hint?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to use the [DataFrame.hint()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.hint) method to add a [Range Join hint](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/join-performance/range-join.html#enable-range-join-using-a-range-join-hint) to my join.

I have two tables: `minutes` and `events`.

The minutes table has the `minute_start` and `minute_end` columns that are time in seconds since a fixed moment in time. Naturally, their values are multiples of 60.

The events table has similar `event_start` and `event_end` columns, only for events. Events can start and end at any second.

For each event, I need to find all the minutes it overlaps with.

I'm trying this on Databricks (runtime 5.1, Python 3.5):

```py
# from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType

# minutes = spark.sparkContext\
#                .parallelize(((0,  60),
#                              (60, 120)))\
#                .toDF(StructType([
#                          StructField('minute_start', IntegerType()),
#                          StructField('minute_end', IntegerType())
#                        ]))

# events = spark.sparkContext\
#               .parallelize(((12, 33),
#                             (0,  120),
#                             (33, 72),
#                             (65, 178)))\
#               .toDF(StructType([
#                         StructField('event_start', IntegerType()),
#                         StructField('event_end', IntegerType())
#                       ]))

events.hint("range_join", "60")\
      .join(minutes,
            on=[events.event_start   < minutes.minute_end,
                minutes.minute_start < events.event_end])\
      .orderBy(events.event_start,
               events.event_end,
               minutes.minute_start)\
      .show()
```

Without the `hint` call, the result is as expected:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
|event_start|event_end|minute_start|minute_end|
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
|          0|      120|           0|        60|
|          0|      120|          60|       120|
|         12|       33|           0|        60|
|         33|       72|           0|        60|
|         33|       72|          60|       120|
|         65|      178|          60|       120|
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

With the `hint`, I get the exception:

```
AnalysisException: 'Range join hint: invalid arguments Buffer(60);'
```

When I tried passing the `60` in the hint as a number as opposed to a string, it complained that a parameter of a hint must be a string.

I'm **not on Azure**, but I expect the outcome would be the same.

Has anyone had a similar issue and found a solution or knows where I'm making a mistake?

**UPDATE 1**

(Currently, I'm trying it on Databricks Runtime 6.1, Python 3.7.3, Spark 2.4.4)

I thought I missed that the parameters are expected as an iterable, so I tried again, with `events.hint("range_join", [60])`. Same complaint about the argument not being a string: `TypeError: all parameters should be str, got 60 of type <class 'int'>`.

I'm wondering if Databricks' version of Spark is behind.

This is in Spark [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L470):

```py
def hint(self, name, *parameters):
    ... (no checks on `parameters` up to here)

    allowed_types = (basestring, list, float, int)
    for p in parameters:
        if not isinstance(p, allowed_types):
            raise TypeError(
                "all parameters should be in {0}, got {1} of type {2}".format(
                        allowed_types, p, type(p)))

    ... (no checks beyond this point)
```

so a list of `int`s should be allowed.

What I'm getting is `all parameters should be str`, but the GitHub version would say `all parameters should be in (basestring, list, float, int)` if I passed a parameter of a wrong type.

**UPDATE 2**

`hint("skew", "col_name")` appears to be working.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: So far I haven't found a solution.

Comment: I found that instead of using the `.hint()` you can configure your Spark Session config to use the range join bins if you are using Databricks
https://docs.databricks.com/delta/join-performance/range-join.html#enable-range-join-using-session-configuration

Comment: @MarcusLind Yes, that's one thing I've been using, but it seems to be platform-specific, and I'd like the code to work locally, too. You could also just write it in SQL: `spark.sql("SELECT /*+ RANGE_JOIN(events, 60)*/ ... "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Spark source code on GitHub.

[Version 2.4.4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L488) has this:

```py
def hint(self, name, *parameters):
    ...  # no checks on `parameters` up to here

    for p in parameters:
        if not isinstance(p, str):
            raise TypeError(
                "all parameters should be str, got {0} of type {1}".format(p, type(p)))

    ...  # no checks beyond here
```

But from [version 3.0.0-preview-rc1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.0-preview-rc1/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L470) on, the source has this:

```py
def hint(self, name, *parameters):
    ...  # no checks on `parameters` up to here

    allowed_types = (basestring, list, float, int)
    for p in parameters:
        if not isinstance(p, allowed_types):
            raise TypeError(
                "all parameters should be in {0}, got {1} of type {2}".format(
                    allowed_types, p, type(p)))

    ...  # no checks beyond here
```

So it seems as though version 2.4.4 had a bug, that has been fixed in versions starting from 3.0.0-preview-rc1.

Comment: I also checked 2.4.5, and the bug is still there, so we probably have to wait for 3.0 on Databricks.

Comment: Created a PR to cherry-pick this back into the 2.4 branch as well: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/28238

Comment: @FokkoDriesprong, doesn't look like they agree it's a bug because Range Join isn't in the Apache pySpark API docs. Well, I'd argue `.hint("range_join", param)` raises an exception that does not say that `"range_join"` is an invalid hint type, but rather says  that`param` is merely the wrong type, suggesting that there still exist correct types for `param`. So basically that allows to use any `"hint_type"` regardless of whether JVM actually knows how to handle it or not. That feels to me like poor exception handling at best. I realize you can define your own hints, it's open source, but...

Comment: @FokkoDriesprong contd... the code never reaches a point when it realizes, "Oh, but this type of hint isn't defined anywhere in your code, so there's your exception now." Though I don't feel strong about pushing this on